# is there an function to make static formula while input a new data

Tags: google-sheets-formula

is there a way to create a static formula for a new cells when I put a new value within on google sheets.
for example : I put a value on A1 and B1 and the result will come in C1 without typing the formula ( like already defined )

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMlU3.png)

so I didn't have to drag the formula to the bottom

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLwMT.png)

I have try to put the formula on the header columns so I expected the formula will apply to entire column, but the result still in one cell on C1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with arrayformula. It will automatically drag until the bottom of the column automatically:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A="","",A1:A+B1:B))
```

[image]